# Retrieve values from List<T> property and cast to Dictionary<string,string> C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, casting

Here is the situation:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<Bar> barITems{get; set;}
}
public class Bar
{
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public string Address{get; set;}
}
```

And I need to create Dictionary where key - Bar class property name and value - Bar class relevant value. Here what I did try:

```
    Type a = typeof(Foo);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = a.GetProperties();           
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {                       
        if(property.Name == "barItems")
        {
          var barProperty = property.GetValue(Foo);
          var itemList= barProperty as IEnumerable;
          var barDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
          barDictionary = itemList;  //how to cast it ?           
          continue;
        }
        fooDictionary.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(Foo).ToString());
    }
```

Comment: And what problems are you having with what you've tried?

Comment: @Servy Unable to cast it into Dictionary from IEnumerable

Comment: Your Dictionary should be Dictionary<string,List<string>>

Comment: That makes sense.  itemList is of type IEnumerable, and you try to assign it to a Dictionary that doesn't accept a List<string>.  Why are you using Reflection when you could just roll through your list and assign the key-value pairs for the dictionary that way?

Comment: I tried to test your code but it has an error in this line: var barProperty = property.GetValue(Foo); Foo is a type but you used as a variable.

Answer (score 7):

You can't cast it but you can use ToDictionary:

```
itemList.ToDictionary(s=>s.Name, s.Address);
```

Comment: This way you are also clearer on what is the PK for your collection.